# How to remove the outer border of applications folders in GNOME with the Blur my Shell extension?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using the [Blur my Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/) extension on GNOME Shell. How can I remove the outer border from the GNOME applications folders?

[image: gnome apps folder]

Comment: gnome-tweaks app also has pretty decent customization options for that type of stuff :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Open Blur my Shell's options.
2. Go to the *Overview* tab.
3. In *Application folder dialogs style* select *Transparent* from the drop-down menu.

   [image: Blur my Shell Overview tab]
4. Your applications folders should then look like this:

   [image: Apllications folder without border]